# How to pass a set of values from one Jmeter Thread group to another

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I'm stuck with a scenario of passing a set of values which I get as the output of one thread group's execution to another thread group. I have been using "Beanshell assertion" to do the same by using the

```
 ${**__setProperty**(categoryID, ${categoryID})}
```

method only for one category. But the issue came when I started running the thread group in a loop for 5 category's so that the value of categoryID gets set with the category's thread's output value. These two screenshots may help understand the testplan I'm following:

[image: CourseCrationThread]

[image: GetBatchNotCouse]

So as per the first picture depicts, I have total 5 threads running in 12 loops. Now as I mentioned, I need these 5 categoryID's to get stored separately so that I can get it separately and use it for the next thread group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save different variables per thread using [__threadNum](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function

```
 ${__setProperty(categoryID_${__threadNum}, ${categoryID})}
```

And then get it using same function:

```
${__property(categoryID_${__threadNum})}
```